# Can we use "whisky" to describe a squirrel going up a tree?

Tags: meaning, poetry

I am confused that the term "[whisky](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/whisky)" is used in the poem The Squirrel to describe a squirrel going up a tree (though 'whisky' denotes a drink). According to the Cambridge Dictionary, "whisky" denotes:

> **NOUN**
>
> B2 a strong, pale brown **alcoholic drink**, originally from Scotland and Ireland, made from grain such as barley, maize, or rye

But confusingly, this word (whisky) is used in the following poem:

> **The Squirrel** (Anonymous)
>
> **Whisky, frisky,**
>   **Hippity hop;**
>   **Up he goes**
>   **To the tree top!**
>
> Whirly, twirly,
>   Round and round,
>   Down he scampers
>   To the ground.
>
> Furly, curly
>   What a tail!
>   Tall as a feather
>   Broad as a sail!
>
> Where's his supper?
>   In the shell,
>   Snappity, crackity,
>   Out it fell.

Please pardon me, if I am mistaking the poem.

Comment: Look up *whisk*.

Comment: @michael, I looked up 'whisk' but the term 'whisky' is **not an adjective**.

Comment: Look up *poetic license*. -- Note also the pattern: Whisk-y, frisk-y;  Whirl-y, twirl-y; Furl-y, curl-y.

Comment: @Ahmed A dictionary cannot list all constructible variants of a given word (such as conjugations, cases, diminutives, plurals) since that would make a dictionary several times longer without any real benefit. I would assume “whisky” wasn’t in the dictionary you consulted because it’s rarely used and can be constructed from words that _are_ in the dictionary. An unfortunately confusing case, but not all forms of all words can be in the dictionary, so the fact that the adjective interpretation wasn’t in your dictionary doesn’t mean whisky is not an adjective.

Comment: "Whisky" might connote "whiskers", cause squirrels have whiskers.

Comment: It's not exactly nonsense, but it is mostly made up, just for the sound effect.

Comment: If you drink enough whisky you'll see squirrels and other things going up trees.

Comment: @Robusto Or down trees, or sideways trees.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is based upon a misunderstanding of "to whisk" and its adjective.

Comment: @Greybeard Agreed. The question is about understanding rather than meaning. “Whisky” refers to the way that the tail is whisked around, just as in the following verse “whirly” refers to the way the animal whirls around.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It’s a rare word (or expression since it collocates as “whisky frisky”), but it is in the Oxford English Dictionary (OED.com) so it’s not a neologism. It’s a poem, so the author likely isn’t worried about using a rare word. In any case the meaning is clear. It is defined as:

> Light and lively, flighty.

And it was used as far back as 1782:

> Talking in such a whisky frisky manner that nobody can understand him.
>
> [Cecilia](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/ecco/004865984.0001.005/1:4.4?rgn=div2;view=fulltext)

More examples:

- [The politician out-witted, a comedy, in five acts](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/evans/N17012.0001.001/1:3.4?rgn=div2;view=fulltext) (1788)
- [The fortunes of Nigel](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_fortunes_of_Nigel/kiNDAQAAMAAJ?q=%22whisky%22+%22frisky%22+-Hippity&gbpv=1&bsq=%22whisky%22%20%22frisky%22#f=false) (1836)
- [The Keepsake](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Keepsake/nYFRAAAAcAAJ?q=%22whisky%22+%22frisky%22+-Hippity&gbpv=1&bsq=%22whisky%22%20%22frisky%22#f=false) (1840) in quotes
- [A Publisher and His Friends](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Publisher_and_His_Friends/Y5g9AAAAYAAJ?q=%22whisky%22+%22frisky%22+-Hippity&gbpv=1&bsq=%22whisky%22%20%22frisky%22#f=false) (1843)
- [Eliza Cook's Journal](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Eliza_Cook_s_Journal/PGEoAQAAMAAJ?q=%22whisky%22+%22frisky%22+-Hippity&gbpv=1&bsq=%22whisky%22%20%22frisky%22#f=false) (1854) although it might be a reference to alcohol, I’m not sure

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, does the Oxford Dictionary also list "furly"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA it doesn’t list furly.

Comment: Ahh, interesting. It would be especially nice to know how old the children's poem/rhyme is.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It dates back to at least [1935](https://books.google.com/books?id=JTUNAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22whisky%20frisky%22%20squirrel&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=Hop), although it’s called “Whisky Frisky” there and I can’t see the entire poem. It might be earlier than that though.

Comment: I found a [1932 edition](https://books.google.it/books?id=M9YNAAAAMAAJ&q=%22Furly+curly%22&dq=%22Furly+curly%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFo5CZmLjfAhWFUZAKHaGJD5QQ6AEIgwEwEw)

Comment: Its not *that* rare. Its still used in cooking a lot, and I hear "whisked away" or "whisked off to .. " a fair bit.

Answer (score 20):

Interestingly, the expression **“whisky-frisky”**, spelled with a hyphen, is an example of a **[reduplication](http://www.oxfordbibliographies.com/view/document/obo-9780199772810/obo-9780199772810-0036.xml)**, albeit very rare. Similar to  *binomial pairs*, reduplication is usually two words but which rhyme together, e.g. *hoity-toity*,  *jeepers-creepers*, *pitter patter*, and *topsy-turvy*. In the English language, whisky-frisky stood for someone drunk on whisk(e)y and probably unsteady on their legs, so quite the opposite of a sprinting squirrel!

The author of the book *[History, meaning and the sheer joy of words](https://books.google.it/books?id=LzUnGylOEeQC&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=%22whisky%20frisky%22%20reduplicative&source=bl&ots=-iKfykKbRH&sig=gIpfmZWKQwREf2LbgmmBcfWLjZQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUw6iXkLjfAhVBFZAKHSqeD2AQ6AEwAnoECA8QAQ#v=onepage&q=%22whisky%20frisky%22%20reduplicative&f=false)*, Vivian Cook, says it is of American origin and is virtually obsolete. She also lists other examples that are mostly forgotten: *kitch-witch*, *holums-jolums*, and *hitherum-ditherum*, note the hyphen that joins the two words together, this is missing from the poem cited by the OP.

However, the poem *The Squirrel* is filled with reduplicative  expressions that small children find particularly appealing due to their quirkiness and rhythmical beats.

- Hippity hop (nowadays *hoppity-hop*)
- Whirly twirly
- Furly curly
- Snappity crackity

EL&U has many questions and answers dedicated to this fascinating linguistic phenomenon, I would warmly recommend the OP to delve into its archives: [Questions tagged reduplication](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=reduplication)

Comment: +1 Apparently I am a holdout for _hippity-hop_ - and a _twirly-whirly_-er to boot.

Comment: Rather than the torpor of the solidly drunk, it might be referring to the quick-fire bonhomie of someone a little tipsy who's lost most of their inhibitions but before they've lost their wakefulness.

Comment: @WillCrawford ah, yes. You're right, I hadn't thought of that

Comment: I think you've landed a little wide of the mark here in places, in this poem he's simply describing how the squirrel whisks up the tree in a frisky fashion, I'm pretty sure he's not suggesting the squirrel is drunk.

Comment: @Pelinore my answer is explaining that "whisky-frisky" used to have a specific meaning, which does not fit in with the poem. I never suggested that the squirrel was drunk. Laurel's answer is the one the OP should select. But it is nevertheless true that many of the words are reduplications.

Comment: ^ I'd agree there, apologies for for the misinterpret of that bit of your answer.

Comment: The use of a comma rather than a hyphen (it's not simply that there's no hyphen) could be a cue to the intended pacing of the line, with the comma hinting at a between words that's natural in the other pairs ("whirly, twirly" etc.)

Answer (score 11):

As other answers have pointed out, this particular example of rhyming repetition dates back at least as far as the 18th century, being used in "[The Race](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_RKkUqgDFTw0C/page/n43?q=%22whisky+frisky%22)," a satirical poem by Cuthbert Shaw (**1766**), who considered it one of his "favourite words" (see footnote).

[image: The Race]

> Prove then, oh Goddess! to my labours kind,
>   And let the sons of Dulness lag behind,
>   While hoity-toity, whisky-frisky<sup>49</sup>, I
>   On ballad-wings spring forth to victory.'
>
> <sup>49</sup>A favourite word of this author. See Education, a poem.

It was also used in volume three of [*Cecilia*](https://archive.org/details/britishnovelists42barbuoft/page/174?q=%22whisky+frisky%22), a book in five volumes by Frances Burney (**1782**), and in a rhyming chorus in "[The Highland Reel](https://archive.org/details/dramaticworksofj04okeeiala/page/192)," a **1788** farce by John O'Keeffe.

[image: The Highland Reel chorus]

> Whiskey, frisky,
>   Prancing, dancing,
>   Sorrow kick to Nick the De'el,
>   Care or trouble who can feel,
>   Lilting up the Highland Reel.

The "Whisky Frisky" poem itself appears in an **1871** children's book, [*Little-Folk Songs*](https://archive.org/details/littlefolksongs00whit/page/10), by Alexina B. White.

[image: Little-Folk Songs title page]

[image: Little-Folk Songs date]

[image: Whisky Frisky 1871]

In that early version, there was a fifth stanza that is missing from most later versions of the poem:

> Stir the fire,
>       Put on the pot,
>   Here's his supper
>       Hissing hot!

Around the previous turn of the century, the poem was included in a children's reading primer series, [*The Culture Readers: Embodying the natural method in reading*](https://archive.org/details/culturereaderse00wargoog/page/n52), by Ellen E. Kenyon-Warner, Pd.D. (Doctor of Pedagogy), in a volume aimed at the "second half year".

[image: Culture Readers title page]

This "natural method" involves the child reading texts of interest and performing targeted study of words encountered in their reading.

[image: Culture Readers instructions]

The "Whisky Frisky" poem is presented with a list of related vocabulary words, some of which appear in the poem and others of which are related through rhyme or similar spelling lessons (e.g. silent A in read, lead, bead).

[image: Whisky Frisky 1902]

Answer (score 4):

I'd also mention that in poetry, words can be used purely for their sound or effect. As an extreme example, there's a famous English poem "[Jabberwocky](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/42916/jabberwocky)" by Lewis Carroll (who also wrote the stories of Alice in Wonderland), which begins,

> ’Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
>   Did gyre and gimble in the wabe:
> All mimsy were the borogoves,
>   And the mome raths outgrabe.

This is complete nonsense, but it sounds like English and "feels" right to a reader. Just based on the sounds and shapes of the words, they bring to mind possible meanings, and more importantly convey the emotion and feeling of the fantastical world where the Jabberwock lives.

In this poem, "whisky" may be used just for its sound and similarity to the word "whisk", which as Pelinore points out means sudden and quick movement. The "-y" suffix makes it sound even more light and playful, and it rhymes with "frisky".

Comment: Dr Seuss built many of his rhyming children's stories on this concept of "purely for their sound effect" made-up words. https://www.wordnik.com/lists/words-made-up-by-dr-seuss

Comment: On an even more nonsensical theme, Edward Lear wrote a poem using real but non-English words for their sounds, deliberately making them inappropriate. http://www.nonsenselit.org/Lear/ll/cummerbund.html

Answer (score 4):

It seems that even when this "whisky frisky" phrase was being used in the 18th century, there was discussion over what it might mean.

In 1787, [George Colman "the Elder"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Colman_the_Elder) published a work titled *Prose on Several Occasions; Accompanied With Some Pieces in Verse*. In Volume II of this work is a parody called "[Letter from Lexiphanes, containing Proposals for a Glossary or Vocabulary of the Vulgar Tongue, intended as a Supplement to a larger Dictionary](https://archive.org/details/proseonseveraloc02colmuoft/page/96?q=%22whifky+frifky%22)."

This letter begins:

> Tuesday, Dec. 4, 1770.
>
> Sir,
>
> There are in every language, ancient and modern, certain heterogeneous words and anomolous expressions, which render it more difficult to be acquired by students and foreigners than even the most licentious idiomatick phrases, or the most irregular combination of sentences.

After further explanation, he continues:

> To remedy this defect in English Literature, I have, with infinite labour, compiled a Vocabulary or Glossary, intended as a Supplement to a larger and more solemn Dictionary. It is easy to foresee that the idle and illiterate will complain that I have increased their labours by endeavoring to diminish them, and that I have explained what is more easy by what is more difficult -- *Ignotum per, ignotius.*

The letter writer presents a list of definitions for terms such as "higgled-piggledy" and "tit for tat" and "hodge-podge," after which he declares the need for such a dictionary by presenting examples of terms that yet need to be defined:

> Philological Disquisitions are but ill adapted to the readers of a sugacious paper. Having, therefore already given a sufficient indication of my purpose to the Philosopher, the Academick, and the Scholar, I shall at present add no further interpretations; but in order to convince the learned of the Necessity and Importance of the work announced to them, I shall somewhat enlarge the catalogue of terms that demand explication; which like base metal among legitimate coin, have, by long usage, become current in our language; and without which the commerce of the world, or even the traffick of letters, can with difficulty be maintained either with profit or delectation. To explain them may be some glory: it would be more substantial fame to contribute to their extirpation.
>
> CATALOGUE.
>   Wishy-washy,
>   Mess-medly,
>   Fiddle-faddle,
>   ...
>   Tory-rory,
>   **Whisky-frisky**,
>   Snickersnee,
>   ...

He concludes:

> He who writes the Dictionary of any Tongue, may be considered as labouring in a coal-mine; but he who collects the Refuse of a Language, claims more than ordinary commiseration, and may be said to sift the cinders.
>
> I am, Sir,
>   Yours, &c.
>   LEXIPHANES.

The name "Lexiphanes" is a wordplay on the Greek words for "word" and "show" or "appear."

[image: Colman letter from Lexiphanes]

It might be worth noting that in the 18th century, the adjective "whisky" was not a nice way to describe someone.

The 18th century Lancashire satirist [John Collier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Collier_(caricaturist)) wrote under the pen name "Tim Bobbin." He is best known for *[A View of the Lancashire Dialect, or, Tummus and Mary](https://archive.org/details/tim_bobbin_pb_librivox)* (1746), which he followed up with *[The Lancashire dialect, or, The adventures and misfortunes of a Lancashire clown](https://archive.org/details/McGillLibrary-PN970_C54_B63_1822-1755)*, which contains the indecipherable (if you're not a Lancastrian) [exchange](https://archive.org/details/McGillLibrary-PN970_C54_B63_1822-1755/page/n31) between Tummus (Thomas) and Meary (Mary):

> *T.* Is't think on ot teaw looks o bit whisky, chez whot Seroh o'Rutchot's is.
>   *M.* I yeard um sey ot gexing's o knit' lying, un ot proof oth' pudding's ith' eyghting. -- So fareweel, Tummus.

A mid-19th-century revision by Samuel Bamford of the latter work, titled *[Dialect of South Lancashire: Or, Tim Bobbin's Tummus and Meary ; with His Rhymes and an Enlarged and Amended Glossary of Words and Phrases](https://archive.org/details/dialectsouthlan00bamfgoog/page/n170?q=%22whisky+frisky%22)*, includes a glossary that defines "whisky" as "frisky" or "immodest."

[image: frisky immodest]

A similar [revision](https://archive.org/details/cu31924013171131/page/n133) by a different mid-19th-century author, John Corry, defines "whisky" as "whorish."

[image: whorish]

Answer (score 1):

Good answers in the other two but I think you (or at least *some*) might benefit from an answer in simpler terms, the "whisky" in the poem is derived from the word [whisk](https://www.google.com/search?q=whisk%20meaning&rlz=1C1NHXL_enGB711GB711&oq=Whisk%20&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.5679j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

> take or move (someone or something) somewhere suddenly and quickly.

The author has simply added a few letters to it so that it rhymes with frisky.

He's a poet, they're allowed to do things like that :)

Comment: We prefer that you track down definitions to the dictionary they came from, and link to that (rather than to Google).

Comment: @Scott : The dictionary it came from is my head & it's not been digitized yet so we'll have to make do.

Comment: If the dictionary is in your head, why are you linking to Google at all?  [Google is your friend.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22take+or+move+%28someone+or+something%29+somewhere+suddenly+and+quickly%22+dictionary)

Comment: @Scott : ^ not knowing who might be reading (their age or ability in English), for the soundbite.

Answer (score 1):

For totaly clarity but also not to contradict at all the other great and well researched answers, no, you cannot use 'whisky' to describe a squirrel going up a tree.

For example, in:

> The whisky squirrel retrieved a number of acorns before coming back down.

or

> The squirrel was very whisky.

to a modern reader (and most likely from past centuries, would wonder what why would you talk about a drunk rodent like that. A whisky-soaked squirrel? A squirrel that looks like a whisk?

Used by itself, 'whisky' is either a misspelled liquor used strangely, or a weird way to say it looks like a whisk. Either way, it'd be a cumbersome unnatural (almost ungrammatical) way to say it.

Yes, it has all those past usages, but no, you don't really want to use 'whisky' the way you suppose in your title.

Comment: Not misspelled. Scotch whisky prefers that spelling.